# Is there a tool for inlining the styles declared in an automatically generated CSS class?

Tags: html, svg, web, adobe-illustrator

Without going into why I'm here, I'll tell you what I have. I have a file of containing thousands of SVGs made with Adobe Illustrator. The SVGs are styled via `class` attributes referencing one or many auto-generated CSS classes.

For example:

```html
<style>
    .st0{fill:#2595FF;}
    .st1{fill:#bada55;}
    .st2{fill:#f0f0f0; color:#fafafa;}
</style>
<svg>
    <line class="st0" x1="27.8" y1="80.5" x2="39" y2="80.5"/>
</svg>
```

I'd like to inline the styles declared in the CSS classes. I can do this manually, but that won't scale because there hundreds of CSS classes!

Example:

```html
<!--  see how I've (manually) inlined the declarations of class .st0? -->
<svg>
    <line fill="#2595FF" x1="27.8" y1="80.5" x2="39" y2="80.5"/>
</svg>
```

Is there a tool for doing this automatically? I don't have a license for Illustrator or anything proporietary like that.

Comment: Do I understand right that the file is a .svg file with multiple `<symbol>` elements? Where in that file are the styles defined? Are there multiple `style` elements?

Comment: Yes. It's a single file with many <symbol> tags between one pair of <svg> tags. In-between each <symbol> there are <style> tags that define a particular SVG. I realize what I want is like a HTML `<style>` inliner used for HTML emails. I tried sticking my SVG code into one, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

in svg options when saving from illustrator, choose Style Attributes in CSS properties menu. this way illustrator will inline styles directly to the tag

Answer (score 0):

Your description clearly contravenes CSS rules. Any conforming editor would interpret the CSS cascade, and the last style rule selecting a certain class would win.

Fortunately, not everthing you encounter is standard-conformant. You can try the following

1. Open the file with [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org), it's freely available.
2. Open Edit -> XML-Editor. In the left-hand treeview, select the root svg element.
3. In the right-hand attributes view, click on any attribute line. In the lower part, to the right click the "Set" button.

   In a short test I just did that triggered the inlining of the styles, and astonishingly gave different fill attributes to elements with the same class, just as intended by AI.
4. Save as "Plain SVG".